# convert unix timestamp php

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a database that stores the time for me. I insert it from PHP using

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I then use this function to convert it to a unix timestamp in PHP

```
function convert_datetime($str) 
{
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $str);
list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
list($hour, $minute, $second) = explode(':', $time);

$timestamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

return $timestamp;
}
```

What I now need to do is convert this timestamp to the date and time in this format:
yyyymmddhhmmss (without any hyphens, dashes, colons, etc).

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: http://www.php.net/date has a complete list of `date()`'s formatting parameters

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `strtotime` and `date` function:

```
echo date('Ymdhis', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [date](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$date = date("YmdHis", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

here you go

```
print date("YmdHis",unixtimestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using mysql, it has a `DATE_FORMAT` function. You can call it like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`datefield`, "%Y%m%d%H%i%s") AS `date_formatted` FROM table;
```

So you get an already formatted date from your database.

Comment: I would also recommend this approach rather than using PHP. I haven't done any benchmarks but I suspect it's orders of magnitude faster. Also, use `NOW()` in SQL, instead of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` in PHP for the insertion, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use the right format :

```
date('YmdHis');
```