# How can I find the number of seconds elapsed since mySQL timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Exactly as the subject: I got an automatic mySQL timestamp in variable and I want to know how much seconds had passed since it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$delta = time() - strtotime($mySqlTime) ;
```

Comment: thx! solved it the other way around using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707506/convert-unix-timestamp-php and BTW the problem was that I mistakenly kept updating the row therefor the SQL timestamp! lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want the MYSQL Function take a look at [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

```
TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`timestamp`)
```

Comment: `TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(NOW(), timestamp ) )` can give an integer value of seconds elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

call php's time() function and subtract that result from the mysql timestamp.

To convert the mysql timestamp to the correct format, use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: What is the format of the mysql timestamp? You will want to convert that into a unix timestamp and then subtract that.

Comment: 2012-10-02 18:30:26 - how can I convert it?

Comment: use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert that string to a Unix timestamp

Comment: thx! solved it the other way around using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707506/convert-unix-timestamp-php and BTW the problem was that I mistakenly kept updating the row therefor the SQL timestamp!