# PHP date timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a question about the way the PHP `date()` function works when converting it into a Unix timestamp.

I have used the `date()` function to create a date in the form `July-7-2014.` When I get the Unix timestamp for this date, I would expect it to be something which corresponds to `07 July 2014 00:00:00 GMT`. Instead, I'm getting a timestamp which corresponds to `07 July 2014 20:14:00 GMT`.

What I'm really asking is: for what reason does the timestamp give me `20:14:00` as hours, minutes, seconds and not something like `00:00:00`?

Comment: date() doesn't create a date; it formats a timestamp as a string that (to human beings) resembles a date.... now how are you getting the unix timestamp for this date? Are you using strtotime() or what?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear since you're not showing the part that turns your string into a UNIX timestamp. However, the answer is most likely `strtotime`, which replaces all missing information from the current time. You'd need to clarify why `00:00:00` is any more valid than `20:14:00` in your mind.

Comment: Exactly what I said in the last part deceze and my comment was deleted.

Comment: @deceze I'm currently using `$completedDate = new DateTime($date); $date = $completedDate->getTimestamp();` to get the timestamp because the `strtotime` documentation said it's not advisable to use `strtotime` for mathematical operations. I tried `strtotime` though and that gave me the same result. `00:00:00` isn't necessarily more valid than `20:14:00` but I can't understand why it's giving me that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for anyone who is wondering. For some reason, when using a `date()` format which uses a month's full name (e.g. the `date(F-j-Y)` format I was using) the timestamp begins to behave a little bizarrely. I tried using the `date(m-d-Y)` format (`07-07-2014`) and the timestamp returned the expected `00:00:00` value for hours, minutes, and seconds. I'm not sure if it's intended for dates in that format to return arbitrary hours, minutes, and seconds, but I found out why I was getting those results.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over here.

[convert unix timestamp php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707506/convert-unix-timestamp-php?rq=1)

The unix timestamp gives the current time that the server has.